# How to set/define the value for the label in the minimap

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Since Wagtail 4.1 a new minimap component is available in the editor interface.

For newly added blocks, the defined icon and the `Meta` class label of a subclassed `StructBlock` are shown.

However, after saving the page, the first field/block of the `StructBlock` is used as the label in the minimap.

How can I specify which field/block or text should be used as the label in the minimap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimap uses the `label_format` attribute of the `Meta` class.

```py
class PanelBlock(StructBlock):
    headline = blocks.CharBlock(label=_('Headline'))
    text = blocks.RichTextBlock(label=_('Text'))

    class Meta:
        label = _('Infobox')
        icon = 'doc-empty'
        label_format = 'This is the label'  # <- This will be used as the label
```

> **label_format** – Determines the label shown when the block is collapsed in the editing interface. By default, the value of the first sub-block in the StructBlock is shown, but this can be customised by setting a string here with block names contained in braces - for example label_format = "Profile for {first_name} {surname}"

Source: https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/streamfield/blocks.html#wagtail.blocks.StructBlock